# Exporting from BigQuery not working

Tags: excel, csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to export a large CSV dataset from BigQuery. The file is over 90000 rows, so BigQuery prompts me to export the table to Google Cloud Storage

...so I did that with the options of:

Export format: CSV,

Compression: GZIP

Google Cloud Storage URI: my_bucket/2015/feb.csv

After a few minutes, the dataset appears in my Google Cloud Storage. Then I go to download it from there. The file is about 200MB, when I finally open it, the excel sheet is crammed with Wingdings, none of the data made it through.

**Did I go wrong somewhere? How can I download and open this file properly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 mv feb.csv feb.csv.gz
 gunzip feb.csv.gz
```

According to the question, you asked for a compressed file, so un-compress it first.

Comment: just to add to this a little explanation: even though you provided extention of csv it is still gzip file that is being created in GCS, so as Felipe suggesting - you should add gz extention to it and unzip it, after which you will get csv file that you can open with Excel.